# Python Selenium close popup advert. window

Tags: python, selenium

I was start to learn Selenium (with Python), when driver open website a popup advert is shown. I tried close it by using:

```
try:
  if driver.switch_to_alert() != None:
      clink = driver.find_element_by_id("CloseLink")
      clink.click()
      driver.implicitly_wait(10)
except Exception, e:
  print e
```

I found it have a-link with mentioned ID, and it seems to reach it (dots on browser appears) but not close advert... So elements under is are not reachable.
My question are:

1. how close advert
2. is possible to push element-button under popup window with advert?

When popup exist, exception '...is not clickable at point...' is rising,
Thanks in advance :-)
Example of this site is: http://www.iswinoujscie.pl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to wait until "`element_to_be_clickable`":

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait


driver.get("http://www.iswinoujscie.pl/")
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,"CloseLink"))).click()
```

Comment: Thank you DurdenP - it works, but what about 2nd question? I suppose it is impossible, I'm right?

Comment: If you are going to click an element you are waiting for, you should wait for it to be clickable, `element_to_be_clickable()`. Presence just means that it's in the DOM. You could get intermittent failures if the page loads slowly.

Comment: Also, you might as well just wait for `(By.ID,"CloseLink")` to be clickable. There's not much point in waiting for `adPopUp7` then click on `CloseLink`. Just wait and click on `CloseLink`.

Comment: @WikS.eu To your second question, yes... you can click on the element under a popup using JavascriptExecutor. If you are writing automation to test user scenarios, then you should generally avoid JavascriptExecutor because it allows you to do things that a user can't do, like click something under a popup. But, if you aren't testing user scenarios then it's fine to use.

Answer (score 0):

:-) (next) working solution is:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.proxy import Proxy, ProxyType
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from time import sleep
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary


def my_proxy(PROXY):
    """
    """
    prox = Proxy()
    prox.proxy_type = ProxyType.MANUAL
    prox.http_proxy = PROXY
    prox.socks_proxy = PROXY
    prox.ssl_proxy = PROXY

    capabilities = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities().FIREFOX
    capabilities["marionette"] = False
    prox.add_to_capabilities(capabilities)

    # in my Debian Linux, Firefox is here:
    binary = FirefoxBinary('/usr/lib/firefox-esr/firefox-esr')

    return webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary,
                             capabilities=capabilities)

# PROXY settings:
# -----------------------------
# http://www.freeproxylists.net/
# -----------------------------
driver = my_proxy('52.163.62.13:80')  

# to test, if proxy working:
# driver.get("http://whatismyip.otg")  # "https://www.iplocation.net")
# exit()

driver.get("http://www.iswinoujscie.pl/artykuly/51291")

# check if expected page is open:
assert "iswinoujscie.pl" in driver.title

# with test as end-user:

try:
    if EC.alert_is_present():
        print 'EC.alert_is_present()'
        WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "CloseLink"))).click()
    else:
        print 'hmm... alert not present'
except Exception, e:
  print '-->', e


edit_name = driver.find_element_by_id("nickname")
edit_name.clear()
edit_name.send_keys(u"marinio")

tarea_content = driver.find_element_by_id("commentContent")
tarea_content.clear()
tarea_content.send_keys(u"Ale tu fajna pogoda :-) a jak u was?")

button_send = driver.find_element_by_id("submit")
# only after alert-adverb is closed:
button_send.click()

# or with JSexecutor:
driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('submit').click()")

'''
expected reply:
-----------
[...]
Komentarz zostanie dodany
[...]
'''

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.XPATH, "//body"), u'Komentarz zostanie dodany'))

# driver.close()  # close webbrowser
```

Thanks for the help @DurdenP @JeffC